# Web Service namespace - create a user interface

Tags: c#, web-services

I need to change the namespace of webservice but I guess the namespaces are urns not urls. So how can I asign a custom namespace for web service so that I can use a custom interface as well. Such as logo fo our company. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this may be wrong answer, and you do not need to match urns or urls with namespaces.

```
[WebService(Namespace = "yourXmlWebServiceNamespace")]
```

or

```
[WebService(Namespace = yourclass.XmlWebServiceNamespace)]
class yourclass
{
    public const string XmlWebServiceNamespace = "http://www.abc.com";
}
```

Comment: but sometimes, the view of the webservice page is different. how can I do that?